# JPA managed entity issue

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, locking

I am using JPA and I have an entity called User and find User by id fetches the user from the database for the given id

```
for ( String id: ids) {
    User u = getUser(id);
    u.setName(smthing); // fires one update statement
    u.setDate(smthing); // fires another update statement

}
```

getUser returns a managed entity and hence any set results into the update statement and when the dao is closed these statements are committed. But the problem is User has a @version field and because there are multiple updates that run on commit, it somehow doesnt update the last user in the list. This happens consistently. So it is not some intermittent issue.

```
User {
    @Version
    Date lastUpdatedDate;
}
```

Has someone faced a similar issue. Ideal for me would be to fetch these user objects in detached mode, set the values and then do a bulk update. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using JEE or JSE? if using JEE is your EntityManger a container Managed? if so, try `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)`

Comment: Also have a look at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking `Not sending version to client, only locking on the server` section. might help.